# Help with Conditional Probability Question

Tags: bayes-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

**Susan tosses a fair coin three times. What is the probability that she tosses "all tails" if she tosses at least two tails?**

The probability space is:

```
HHH
HHT
HTT
TTT
THH
TTH
```

The conditional probability formula states that $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

In this case, "$A$" is tossing three tails. I believe the probability of tossing $3$ tails is $\dfrac{1}{6}$. In this case, "$B$" is tossing at least two tails.  I believe the probability of this event is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Then, according to the formula above, the conditional probability of tossing $3$ tails given that she tosses at least $2$ tails is:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Is my understanding correct?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probability of tossing three tails is actually $1/2 \cdot 1/2 \cdot 1/2=1/8$ since they are independent.

Comment: The sample space you provided is only for $1$ toss. Make $2$ more copies of that list in order to revise your computed probabilities for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Wouldn't the probabilities for A and B be the same if we simply made a copy of the original probability space?

Comment: Each copy of the probability space represents one toss, so $3$ copies equates to $3$ tosses. Note that $B$ is *at least $2$* tails, so from counting you will find that $|B|>|A|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes, but based on your current work I am confident you can fix them.

1. You used $P(A\cap B) = \frac16 \cdot \frac12$ for some reason.
   Actually, it can be calculated that $A\cap B=A$.
   Thus, you should have used
   $P(A\cap B)=P(A)=\frac16$, which is different than $\frac16\cdot\frac12$.
2. Your probability space is wrong.
   You forgot

   HTH
   THT

So, the probability spaces has 8 elements instead of 6.
Unfortunately, this means you have to redo all calculations
(and even my numbers from the first mistake are wrong).